# window.open doesn't work in android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to have an OAuth2 implemented for Ionic application
This is my login for:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="left">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"> 
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-content class="padding">
    <img src="img/Exact_Logo.jpg" border="0"></a><br/>
    <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="loginToFoo()">Sign in with Foo Account</a>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and this is my login controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooapp')
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

$scope.signIn = function(user) {
 console.log('Sign-In', user);
 $state.go('tab.home');
}

$scope.loginToFoo = function() {

var URL_AUTH = 'https://foo.com/api/oauth2/auth';
var RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE = 'code';
var CLIENT_ID = '{xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx}';
var REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost/callback';


var loginUrl = URL_AUTH + '?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + 
              '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URL + 
              '&force_login=1&response_type=' + RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE ;

window.open(loginUrl, "_system", "location=yes"); 
};
})
```

I have also added these lines to config.xml:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

Although I have already added cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, as I use 'ionic serve', I can see the correct result in a browser but as I use 'ionic emulate android', in the android emulator, nothing happens as I click on my login button. 
what am I missing in here?

Comment: what should I use then? I read that InAppBrowser is for this  purpose though.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because it was technically in error. By default you cannot open a new window or tab with WebView. However it's seems that InAppBrowser of Cordova has overridden the WebChromeClient and WebViewClient and added the code required to enable opening of new windows and tabs. But not having used it for 2 years, I am unable to figure out what the trouble here is . Sorry about that.

Comment: you have to install the plugins using the CLI, not just putting some values on the config.xml `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Comment: @jcesarmobile I used this line cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

Comment: @jcesarmobile, it's usually not having the`white-list`. This one is yours.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 the OAuth is done with the inAppBrowser, so the white-list shouldn't affect

Comment: @jcesarmobile, You are correct. I see now in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) *The InAppBrowser is not subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links in the system browser.*

Comment: Anyway, there is a plugin for the OAuth, it uses InAppBrowser with _blank option and I suppose it picks some response, using _system makes no sense

Comment: @jcesarmobile I used _blank and as I try to test it in emulator, I get the error message: "Web page not available" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @jcesarmobile, **CORRECTION** After rereading the [documentation for InAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser), it appears that the white-list **IS** used - when `_self` is used as the target. Documentation reads, *_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.*  THIS IS POOR DOCUMENTATION.

Comment: @jcesarmobile, how do I file a bug on this documentation conflict?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I see the conflict indeed. but don't know how to report it or which one to rely on.

Comment: The doc is ok, the thing is the inAppBrowser it's a bit confusing, you only get the inAppBrowser if you use _blank, the inAppBrowser isn't affected by the whitelist. If you use _system, you get a native browser, so no whitelist either, and if you use _self you load on your cordova webview, so the whitelist affect. All that is in the doc

Comment: So, what I want to say is, you have to use _blank and that is not affected by the whitelist, if you get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, you will have to check the emulator connection and the server

Comment: @jcesarmobile as I use _self, the issue is resolved. :) still, the _blank is not working though but it's fine. I can live with that. Thank you!

Comment: @jcesarmobile if you want write the same remark as answer and I mark it as answer.