# Cordova InAppBrowser not working with iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I'm trying to use Cordova InAppBrowser on iOS but it seems it's not working.

I've found some possible solutions: https://goo.gl/G7GfGg http://goo.gl/sYXfRg

Some needs manual modification for the file but I'm using Phonegap Build so there's no way I can modify the plugin, also some stated regarding the config.xml, so here's my current config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget id="au.gov.nal.hearing.myhearing" version="0.10.3" versionCode="624" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <gap:platform name="ios"/>
    <gap:platform name="android"/>

    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' />

    <name>My Hearing</name>
    <description>My Hearing App</description>

    <author email="rene@bywave.com.au" href="http://bywave.com.au/">Renemari Padillo</author>

    <content src="index.html"/>

    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1.0"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="handset"/>

    <access origin="*"/>
    <access origin="*.google.com"/>
    <access origin="*.parse.com"/>
    <access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
    <access origin="*.gstatic.com"/>
    <access origin="*.googleusercontent.com"/>
    <access origin="google.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="parse.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <allow-intent href="*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" version="5.0.4"/>
    <gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.3"/>
    <gap:plugin name="uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion" version="0.1.4"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.0.1"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.0.0"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" version="0.3.10"/>
    <gap:plugin name="com.medlei.pushplugin" version="0.1.2">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="Bd8dbfMRwToBaB8UP0SWZ0ZlgYJ2o1CqMtFqzkuh"/>
        <param name="CLIENT_KEY" value="0ev2Je3JX3ln5XJHTsFTbJwNpG7k5eXpt5l83CVs"/>
    </gap:plugin>
    <icon src="resources/icon.png"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" gap:density="ldpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" gap:density="mdpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" gap:density="hdpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" gap:density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <gap:splash src="resources/splash.png"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" gap:qualifier="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h@2x.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
</widget>
```

So to make things sure, I've also paired the plugin with `ngCordova's` [InAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('tel:' + vm.phone, '_system');
```

index.html

```
<!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

The app didn't produce any error(s), the call link works well w/ Android but not on iOS.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Let me know if you need more technical details.

Thanks

Comment: On iOS, does it just open in the actual window or clicking the button does nothing ? How do you build your project ? eg, do you zip your `www` folder and then  use build.phonegap to generate the iPhone file?

Comment: the button does nothing.
To build the app, I simply pushed the Ionic project to Git (w/ default .gitignore included). Base from what I know, Phonegap Build only needs your config.xml file, of course w/ some default files/folders such as `www`, then I just simply changed the XML namespacing to Phonegap so it would cater it's own config syntax such as `gap:plugin`

Answer (score 1):

@Renesansz,
#10 of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
In addition, the link contains more information specific to iOS.

**I QUOTE:**

> **#10 Not adding the new "white-list", "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml AND "Content Security Policy"**
>
> This is sooo new and obnoxious, one can only have pitty on returning developers. In addition, this was buried in both the Phonegap blog and the Cordova blog.
>
> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let use say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will not have to add the white-list requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

Comment: But, I've added the CSP in my index.html and also added whitelisted urls/routes and have included the whitelist plugin.
(See updated post, I've included my index.html & config.xml)

Comment: @Renesansz, *jcesarmobile* reminded me earlier today that `InAppBrowser` does *not* need the white-list. He is working on [a similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028833/window-open-doesnt-work-in-android-emulator) Follow along, Jcesarmobile is better at debugging these issues that I am. Best of Luck.

Comment: @Renesansz, I just updated that other thread. There is an exception to the rule when using the *InAppBrowser*.

Comment: @Renesansz, I just re-read your post. Let me know, if you are still having problems with iOS. This might be an iOS bug.

Comment: hey @JesseMonroy650, yes, I'm still having this issue. oh noes... do you know any workaround about this?

Comment: Okay. I just took a closer look at you configuration. You seem to have two conflicting entries in the file. Please post the entire `config.xml`

Comment: oh, I see, okay, I've updated my post for full config.xml

Answer (score 0):

@Renesansz,
I'm adding some things you can fix before we get to what might be the problem.

It's clear to me that I should have had you work on the two other major issues which plague most people. In you case, there is a third and fourth issue. The four things you need to do next is:

1. put a version on your compiler - see below
2. source ALL your plugins from NPM - see below
3. put versions on ALL your plugins - see below
4. remove ALL references about `<feature (...)>` - see below

### On 1., 2., & 3.

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #11 **You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

For #6 & #7

> **You did not the version numbers**
> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

While the article is a bit dated, the concepts and directions are correct. Just, make sure you use the new spelling for the name, with the dashes, not the periods.

> **You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**
>
> The rules regarding sourcing your plugins can be rather confusing. The best thing to do is read the blog posts - below. Developers that use CLI can source from github, again see the blog post.
>
> 2015-10-09 - Without announcement, tweet, or blog, the repository change a full week before it was scheduled. I can do nothing, but complain.... This is damm annoying.
>
> NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)

### On 4.

`<feature>` tags are deprecated. That means they are no longer used.
You can [read about it here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features)

#### I QUOTE

> Aside from the `debug-server` feature, the `<feature>` tag is essentially deprecated on *PhoneGap Build* since *PhoneGap APIs* were pluginized. Permissions are now generally managed by individual plugins, and application manifests and permissions can be modified directly using the [config-file element](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html). However for backwards-compatibility, they are still supported and map to device permissions on Android and Windows Phone 8:

In other words, you have a duplicate configuration, and it is doing nothing. Take it out.

Comment: I've corrected my config file based on your possible solution, however the `InAppBrowser` for `tel:` links won't still work on iOS. Also, not all plugins where hosted in NPM, therefore I can't set their source to `source=npm`, else Phonegap Build will generate an error.
(See my updated config.xml above)

Comment: Yes, there are some special rules of InAppBrowser. I have not got them outline. Truthfully between the `white-list` and `InAppBrowser`, it is confusing. I've talked to other developers via forum, they feel the same. [One discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/clRa6v7Iaeg) There is a DANGEROUS setting to use, and it looks like that will be part of the FAQ, as this `whitelist` thing is a mess. You can see my notes (I add to daily) on github [Cordova/Phonegap the white-list system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-system.md)

Comment: On your specific issue, `tel:`, etc - try adding those to your CSP. If you can't source from NPM, remove those plugins and try. Sorry, this thing is so messy, but this is part of the problem with Phonegap development. If you can post to github or similar, I can help more, but otherwise, we continue this way. Best of Luck

Comment: tried doing your suggestions, but still it doesn't work. :(
I see, I'll file a bug report on Github so that the developers would be able to take a look at it. thank you for your time and effort @JesseMonroy650

Comment: @Renesansz Okay. But you want to explicitly state the steps you took for *what is not working as you expect it to*.  Instead of starting with github, you should start with the [Cordova Bug repository](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel), as that is where all bugs end up. I checked Phonegap CLI and Build. They have 14 & 23 bugs, respectively, that are open. I did not look for this. You can find my list of repository & bugs [here](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/bugs.md).

Comment: @Renesansz, I also assume, this is under iOS9, but it may just be InAppBrowser. If you get this resolved, I would appreciate knowing thanks.

Comment: ah, I see2, okay. thank you for the starting point. sure, will update this post once I've been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: "4. feature tags are deprecated" — as far as I can tell this is only for PhoneGap, Cordova does not mention deprecation in [the latest docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/config_ref/index.html#feature).

Comment: It is quite common to confuse the term  "deprecated" and "obsolete". The later means it is no longer available. The former "deprecated" means it will be removed from use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation Best of Luck